# Как передать данные формы в базу и далее успешно их воспроизвести?

Tags: база-данных, php

Язык PHP. Необходимо записать данные в таблицу.

Есть форма. Данные у меня передаются через `GET`.
После нажатия кнопки `GET`, передаётся строка вида:

> http://test.ru/example.php?name=%D0%E0%E4%E8%E0%F2%EE%F0
> &price=500 &izm=%D8%F2%F3%EA%E0 &id=4
> &name=%CA%EE%ED%E4%E8%F6%E8%EE%ED%E5%F0
> &price=14000 &izm=%D8%F2%F3%EA%E0
> &id=3 &name=%D3%E3%EE%EB &price=5656
> &izm=%E4%F0 &id=7 &send=%CE%EA

У меня 4 элемента в таблице. Пользователю необходимо сначала внести изменения в строки базы через `input`, а потом нажатием кнопки `submit` изменения записать в базу.

Не получается сделать так, чтобы перезаписались все строки. Перезаписывается только последняя. Догадываюсь, что процесс нужно производить через `while`, но как сделать, не пойму :-(.

В обработчике я, к примеру, принимаю переменную `name` следующим образом:

```
$name=$_GET['name'].
```

Принимается только последний нейм :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передавайте в гет массив

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="val[1][id]" />
<input type="text" name="val[1][name]" />
<input type="text" name="val[1][izm]" />
```

PHP

```
<? if (!empty($_GET['val'])) foreach ($_GET['val'] as $val) print_r($val); ?>
```

Тут будет видно все, что вы получили.

Comment: @barakh, если ответ помог, ткнуите галку слева от вопроса (принять ответ). Свои очки уважения тратить нежелательно)

Answer (score 0):

обычно если есть элементы с одинаковыми именами то пишут так

```
<input type='text' name='name[]'>
<input type='text' name='name[]'>
<input type='text' name='name[]'>
```

тоесть обозначаем их как массив, ну и принимаем таким образом

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['name'])){ 
$names=$_GET['name'];
$num=count($name);
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){echo $names[$i];}
```

}
//например))
    ?>